# Unable to obfuscate the jar with KlassMaster - Kotlin issue

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a jar and it is built using java and Kotlin. When I try to use the Klass master and obfuscate that, I get the error as follows. By the way I use KlassMaster to Obfuscate.

> FATAL ERROR: Class 'kotlin.jvm.internal.Lambda' not found. Check the classpath option and reopen classes. (1a)

The KlassMaster script looks something like this:-

```
print "Obfuscating the Secret File from the Gradle...";

          
unexclude kotlin.jvm.internal.*;

open ".\nexial.jar";

trimExclude *.*^ public static main(java.lang.String[]);
trim;


obfuscate;

saveAll archiveCompression=asIs 
        deleteEmptyDirectories=true 
        deleteXMLComments=false 
        "c:\Temp\Obfuscated.jar";
```

What is going wrong? Should I install kotlin on my machine?

Comment: Have you tried to [add it to the classpath](https://www.zelix.com/klassmaster/docs/classpathStatement.html)?

Comment: I added all the Kotlin jars needed by installing Kotlin on my machine and then it worked. What I am interested is that the source jar which I am trying to obfuscate already has the appropriate jars. Is there a way to specify those jars?

Answer (score 0):

> Class 'kotlin.jvm.internal.Lambda' not found
> This is a classpath issue.  Zelix KlassMaster performs thorough checks of the classes, methods and fields that are referenced by the classes that are opened for obfuscation at the time of opening those classes.

In this case there are two broad solutions to the problem.  The first solution is to add a JAR containing kotlin.jvm.internal.Lambda to your ZKM Script "classpath" statement (but not your "open" statement).  Now you say that the "source jar which I am trying to obfuscate already has the appropriate jars". I suggest that you check that that is really the case. Often distributions omit classes that are referenced by other classes but not actually used. These omissions can cause these sort of problems.

The second solution is to specify any "missing" classes, fields or methods in a ZKM Script "ignoreMissingReferences" statement that precedes your ZKM Script "open" statement.  Hoever, you should only use this statement if you are sure that the missing classes, fields and methods are really irrelevant to your classes.  See https://www.zelix.com/klassmaster/docs/ignoreMissingReferencesStatement.html for more detail on the "ignoreMissingReferences" statement.